# What is it with car rental and insurance?

Tags: plot-explanation, k-9

In the first *K-9* movie (where Dooley, James Belushi, meets the dog), at the beginning Dooley is about to help a college, in order to get a police dog. He's attacking a house full of drug dealers with a car he rented at a car rental at the other side of the street.

Initially the salesman is completely uninterested in renting him a car, until Dooley mentions he "needs insurance."  At that point the salesman wakes up, and is suddenly full of enthusiasm!

I never understood this (obviously being a) joke, and google is no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Car rental companies make significant profits on accident insurance, so much so that the sales agents are paid commission on the upsell of insurance policies.

Consequently, in this scene, the agent is suddenly excited at the prospect of additional income... at least that is the implications.